# LISP: remove all occurances of a particular variable in a list

Tags: lisp, clisp

I have to write a function from which i can remove all occurances of a particular variable in a list
I am doing programming in Ubuntu Text Editor
My Lisp Code looks lie this:

```
   #! /usr/bin/clisp


(defun my-remove(lst var1)
  (cond
   ((eq lst nil) nil)
   ((eq (car (cdr lst)) var1)(cons (car lst) (my-remove (cdr(cdr lst)) var1)))
    ( t (my-remove (cdr lst) var1))
  )
)
```

The problem is it is not removing any of the element from list

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the first element in the list.  `(car (cdr lst))` is not the first element in the list.

If that element is equal the the one you want to remove, you want to skip it and continue down the list.  If they are not equal, you want to include that element in the result you get from continuing down the list.

In both cases, the "continue down the list"-bit should be the same, the variation is in wether to include the element you are looking at, or not.

Also, you will probably want to compare elements using `eql` or `equal`, not `eq`.  `eql` is the traditional default comparator.

This looks like homework, so I'm not going to give you the code directly, but hopefully this can help nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: I have tried a lot still not able to figure it out...if you can help me with code.....i can reverse engineer it and understand it

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do:

```
if you have an empty list, return the empty list and do no more
if the very first element of the list has the value to be purged:
  return the result of calling the "purge this value" on the rest of the list
otherwise:
  create a new list with:
    the head of the list
    the result of purging the value from the rest of the list
```

What you are doing:

```
if there's an empty list, return the empty list and do no more
if the second element is the value to purge:
  create a new list consisting of:
    the head of the list
    the result of purging the value from the rest of the rest of the list
otherwise:
  return the result of purging the value from the rest of the list
```